# how to customize wordpress internal functions, like adjacent_post_link()

Tags: wordpress, customization

I need to customize the `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` on WordPress.

Per example, I want to shrink permalinks like "Top 5 programming languages that you need to learn" to "Top 5 programing...".

The function responsible for creating the link `isadjacent_post_link()` located at `wp-includes/link-template.php`

Comment: Well, I need to limit chars on next and prev posts links on post pages to avoid bugs - see example: http://www.noamdesign.com/blog/time-doesnt-matter-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

To create a custom adjacent link for posts I can make use of the filter hook next_post_link and previos_post_link;

In the functions.php:

```
function shrink_previous_post_link($format, $link){
    $in_same_cat = false;
    $excluded_categories = '';
    $previous = true;
    $link='%title';
    $format='&laquo; %link';


    if ( $previous && is_attachment() )
        $post = & get_post($GLOBALS['post']->post_parent);
    else
        $post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous);

    if ( !$post )
        return;

    $title = $post->post_title;

    if ( empty($post->post_title) )
        $title = $previous ? __('Previous Post') : __('Next Post');

    $rel = $previous ? 'prev' : 'next';

    //Save the original title
    $original_title = $title;

    //create short title, if needed
    if (strlen($title)>40){
        $first_part = substr($title, 0, 23);
        $last_part = substr($title, -17);
        $title = $first_part."...".$last_part;
    }   

    $string = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post).'" rel="'.$rel.'" title="'.$original_title.'">';
    $link = str_replace('%title', $title, $link);   
    $link = $string . $link . '</a>';

    $format = str_replace('%link', $link, $format);

    echo $format;   
}

function shrink_next_post_link($format, $link){
    $in_same_cat = false;
    $excluded_categories = '';
    $previous = false;
    $link='%title';
    $format='%link &raquo;';

    if ( $previous && is_attachment() )
        $post = & get_post($GLOBALS['post']->post_parent);
    else
        $post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous);

    if ( !$post )
        return;

    $title = $post->post_title;

    if ( empty($post->post_title) )
        $title = $previous ? __('Previous Post') : __('Next Post');

    $rel = $previous ? 'prev' : 'next';

    //Save the original title
    $original_title = $title;

    //create short title, if needed
    if (strlen($title)>40){
        $first_part = substr($title, 0, 23);
        $last_part = substr($title, -17);
        $title = $first_part."...".$last_part;
    }   

    $string = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post).'" rel="'.$rel.'" title="'.$original_title.'">';
    $link = str_replace('%title', $title, $link);   
    $link = $string . $link . '</a>';

    $format = str_replace('%link', $link, $format);

    echo $format;   
}

add_filter('next_post_link', 'shrink_next_post_link',10,2);
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'shrink_previous_post_link',10,2);
```

That all I needed to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` function both come with customization options.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link.  After reading that and learning what the acceptable arguments to the function are,  Test to see if it is possible to pass a php function to the option, like substr().

```
<?php next_post_link('%link',substr('%title',20),FALSE);?>
```

'%link' and '%title' are shortcodes to the post link and title.

Let us know if it works out.

Comment: Hey kevtrout!
Thanks replaying. Your idea doesnt worked, but helped to figure it out my own.

First, the substr is not possible because the wordpress code does not execute the function's arguments.

But looking carefully at the code, Ive seen a hook that I made use of it. So, I will answer this question bellow, so everybody can benefit from it.