# Exclude category post in next_post_link function

Tags: wordpress, pagination

My post is in multiple categories sponsored and other. With the next button, I want the post to be appeared only from sponsored category, not from another category.

I have tried excluding the other category in the `next_post_link` function excluded categories parameter but didn't work.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

In `next_post_link` function try also setting paramter `in_same_cat` to true.

From Codex:

```
<?php next_post_link('format', 'link', 'in_same_cat', 'excluded_categories'); ?>
```

Parameter:

> in_same_cat (boolean) (optional)
>
> Indicates whether next post must be within the same category as the current post. If set to 'true', only posts
>   from the current category will be displayed. If the post is in both
>   the parent and subcategory, or more than one category, the next post
>   link will lead to the next post in any of those categories.

Comment: Yes, I want to overcome the point "the next post link will lead to the next post in any of those categories.". Meaning I need the next link from my choice.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, what you really want is change behavior of the function. If so, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3567178/850010